# Insert into a table while selecting from two tables have no relation with each other

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Fruits              Animals
+------------------+------------------------+
| fruID fruDesc    | animalID   animalDesc  |
|                  |                        |
| 0     Unknown    | 0          Unknown     |
| 1     Apple      | 1          Bird        |
| 2     Banana     | 2          Tiger       |
| 3     Microsoft  | 3          Etc         |
+------------------+------------------------+
NoBrain
+-------------------------------------------+
| someField  fruID  animalID  dateRecorded  |
|                                           |
| 0          3      2         now           |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

I'm using MySQL and trying to write a procedure that accepts two text fields which is expected to be fruDesc and animalDesc, find their related ID and insert those columns into table.

In the scenario above, I should be able to CALL cool_proc('Banana', 'Tiger', 'reallydoesntmatter') and that should insert the NoBrain TBL corresponding row:

```
NoBrain
+-----------------------------------------------+
| someField  fruID  animalID  dateRecorded      |
|                                               |
| 2          2      2         reallydoesntmatter|
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

I can accomplish this by doing multiple queries and selections but I wonder is there anyway to do this with a single query? Without joining (joining is beefy when there are lots of records in rows, -I suppose??-)

Also you might have noticed that I want that proc to be use ID defaults as 0 if there is no match, I suppose I can achieve this by using [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

EDITS: suppose someField is AUTO INCREMENTING

Comment: In NoBrain, do you want date/time values of `NOW` or text value of `reallydoesntmatter`? In either case, you can easily fix Gordon Linoff's solution below.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky, because you allow no matches.  In other databases, you would use `full outer join`.  In MySQL, you would use `union all` and aggregation:

```
insert into nobrain(fruid, aniamlid, daterecorded)
    select max(f.fruid), max(animalid), now()
    from ((select f.fruid, NULL as animalid, NULL as animalDesc
           fruits f
           where f.frudesc = 'Banana'
          ) union all
          (select a.animalid, NULL, animalDesc
           from animals a
           where a.animalDesc = 'Tiger'
          )
         ) af;
```

Comment: Pardon my excuse but i didnt get the point why you are using max() functions?

Comment: @user1046403 . . . To get the two values into the same row.